# Accessing properties of dynamically created subclass (strongly typed)

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

This seems like a pattern that might come up somewhat often so I thought maybe someone on SO knew how this was done. Suppose I have three classes:

```
class Class1 {
    string A { get; set; }
}
class Class2 : Class1 {
    string B { get; set; }
}
class Class3 : Class1 {
    string C { get; set; }
}
```

And a string: `x = "Namespace.Class2";`

The goal is that the library code instantiates an instance of the type given by `x`, which is given to the client. The client then accesses the strongly typed properties of Class2, like so:

```
Class2 test = CreateTheObject();
test.B = "bad wolf";
test.A = "super";
```

You're right that we could reflect the properties, but that isn't strongly typed anymore. A user could do GetProperty(Class2, "SomePropertyThatDoesntExist"). It might eventually throw a runtime exception, but that's a bad user experience. It's the solution I'm coding right now though, since I couldn't figure out how to do what I wanted to do.

**Anyways, on to the question: any idea how this is done?**

Comment: `since I couldn't figure out what I wanted to do.` you should probably figure out what you want first

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish with this? The way you've stated your question, it seems extremely vague. And what's with the `Class2.B = "bad wolf"`? Are they static properties? In order for client code to access a property of an object in a strongly typed fashion, the object has to be cast to a type that has that property. An alternative would be to cast the object to dynamic, but that wouldn't be strongly typed anymore.

Comment: I don't think there is any way for the type of the object you're creating to be known statically the way you're doing it... therefore, there is no way to statically known whether a method/property exists on the object instantiated. Can you not use generics `Instantiate<X>()` or something? Even that seems rather silly. Why do you need to do this? Unless you have a good reason, you might be *doing it wrong*...

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone!
@Thewads: Typo. Edited.
to: JLRishe: Sorry, that was just a lazy heuristic. I explicitly created the object.
to: JeffBridgman: Also sorry, I'm lazy. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Also for @JeffBridgman, the reason I can't use generics is that the final type name (Class2) still needs to be explicitly typed out so that I can access Class2's properties after creating the object as Class1. Class2 has to be typed out if I do Instantiate<Class2> as well.

Comment: You can't be strongly typed if the type in question is unknown at compile type.  And if you know the type at compile-time you could just assign or cast to that type.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Darn, that's the answer I was hoping not to hear. Please reply as a proper answer and I'll mark it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be strongly typed if the type in question is unknown at compile type. And if you know the type at compile-time you could just assign or cast to that type.

You could use the `dynamic` keyword to do what you want.  But, since the type is not known at compile-time, you risk runtime errors if some other type is used that doesn't have the property in question.